# How to display Select statement with a JOIN operation?

Tags: sql, join, select

I need to display the query below as a SELECT statement with JOIN or OUTER JOIN operation.

"Find the total number of trips performed by each driver. List the driving licence numbers associated with the total number of trips. Do not ignore the drivers who performed no trips so far."

I can't figure out how to do the last step (Do not ignore the drivers who performed no trips so far.)

Here is my code so far:

```
use csit115
SELECT TRIP.LNUM, count(TRIP.TNUM)
FROM TRIP
INNER JOIN DRIVER ON TRIP.LNUM=DRIVER.LNUM
GROUP BY LNUM;
```

Comment: Change to a `RIGHT JOIN`... or `LEFT JOIN` `TRIP` to `DRIVER` instead.

Comment: Did anything come to mind when you read the intro to outer joins?

Answer (score 1):

I would used `DRIVER` table as your primary table, and `LEFT JOIN` to `TRIP`.  Try the following instead:

```
use csit115
SELECT DRIVER.LNUM, count(TRIP.TNUM)
FROM DRIVER  
LEFT JOIN TRIP ON DRIVER.LNUM=TRIP.LNUM
GROUP BY DRIVER.LNUM;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
use csit115
SELECT TRIP.LNUM, count(TRIP.TNUM)
FROM DRIVER
LEFT JOIN TRIP ON TRIP.LNUM=DRIVER.LNUM
GROUP BY LNUM;
```